# Is there an idiom similar to "no such thing one can't do for a friend"?

Tags: phrase-request, translation

The title is as close as I could get it. There's a Russian idiom, meaning that you will do everything for a friend. Actually, not only for a friend. It may be for love, or anything else. If I were to translate it literally, I'd say:

> What can't be done for a friend (or for love, you name it)?

Do note, that the question above is rhetorical. Is there a similar idiom in English? What would be the closest translation?

**UPD** Let me add some more context. Your friend asks you something. You find it weird. You wouldn't do such a thing if not for him. But you do it, saying the phrase being discussed.

**UPD** Let me add some more context (2nd try). Your friend and you have different idea of what is right to do in some particular situation. You decide to do what he suggested. But make it clear, that if it were you alone, you'd do it your way.

Comment: There is something called "*all's fair in love and war.*" But I'm not sure if it's enough to describe what you are asking.

Comment: Unlikely, my phrase means, "There's nothing that can't be done for a friend." And yours, from what I can tell, "Any method of achieving a goal is justifiable under some circumstances."

Comment: The literal translation actually conveys the meaning fairly well. I don't think we have a particular idiom in the case of friendship, but for love we have "Love conquers all".

Comment: 'There's nothing I wouldn't do for you.' is the only thing I can think of but I have a feeling there is something closer to what you're asking for.

Comment: In general you could say stuff like "bend over backwards", "go the extra mile", "lay the world at her feet". As for your **UPD**, could you add a sample dialog with the meaning you intend? I can't get the intent of "weird", which is a broad term.

Comment: @user3169 Well, "weird" might be not a good word. Or not always a good one. It might be weird sometimes. But probably more often than not, it's just "going the extra mile", like you suggested, or "out of your way". I had this context in mind. He and I had different idea of what is right to do in some particular situation. I decided to do what he suggested. But made it clear, that if it were me alone, I'd do it my way.

Comment: Love conquers all... it doesn't seem to apply here as well :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What can't be done for a friend?

This works pretty well in English, though it's not a well-known saying.

I think the closest you will get, as far as an English idiom or well-known saying is:

> What are friends for?

Usually this is said after a friend thanks you in response to you doing something for them.  This won't work for *love*, though.

Comment: `"What are friends for?"` seems like a good fit for the friends situation. `"Anything for you"` would work for both friendship and love but that's not really an idiom.

Answer (score 0):

One can use several different phrases to show exclusivity in performing an action

> only for you
>   for no one but you
>   only because of you
>   for you only you

all mean

> I will only do this for you and no one else

one could also use

> anything for you
>   [I'd do anything for you](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ey0D53Dxl3M&t=0m37s)

but the exclusivity is not as explicit and would depend on context.
The phrase may get shortened to

> for you

but context would still be necessary to show exclusivity.